# Can I change the label of the "set" button in a TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, button, datetimepicker

By default you have "set" and "cancel", I would like to change the "set" label to "Find".

Is it possible?

Comment: can you add some code how you are launching timer dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
yourTimePickerDialog.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Find", yourTimePickerDialog);
```

Comment: I did it! By the way it's not BUTTON_POSITIVE but -1 (tried some numbers like 0,1,-1). Do you know why the first selector seems to flash when I press "Find"?

Answer (score 2):

```
TimePickerDialog tp = new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, false);
tp.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        {
        }
    }
});
tp.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        {

        }
    }
});
```

try using the above code..

Comment: In my case, when I set the Positive button and use onClickListener on it, it doesn't; work, whereas, when I tried it for the Negative and Neutral buttons, they don't seem to have any issue. : (

Answer (score 0):

Better create a xml file with time picker and two buttons as you need.

Then you can manually launch a alert dialog with view set to this xml file.

You can set the text as you want to both the buttons also you can manually handle the click events for both the buttons.