# AlertDialog.setButton can't change the button text?

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-dialog

I've set up a custom AlertDialog (actually, a custom TimePickerDialog). I'm using an OnShowListener, to update the buttons text according to a condition. I've put this code on a separate method:

```
private void changeState(){
    if(!SleepAlarm.isActive()){
        Log.d("RPod_MainActivity","SleepAlarm is NOT active");
        this.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON1,(CharSequence)MainActivity.currentContext.getResources().getText(R.string.sleep_enable), sleepEnable);
        this.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON2,(CharSequence)MainActivity.currentContext.getResources().getText(R.string.sleep_cancel), sleepDisable);
    }
    else{
        Log.d("RPod_MainActivity","SleepAlarm is active");
        this.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON1,(CharSequence)MainActivity.currentContext.getResources().getText(R.string.sleep_change), sleepEnable);
        this.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON2,(CharSequence)MainActivity.currentContext.getResources().getText(R.string.sleep_disable), sleepDisable);
    }
    this.setTitle(R.string.sleep_title);
}
```

Once I've pressed the TimePickerDialog.BUTTON1 button, when I show the dialog again the condition is met, and the text should change. But it doesn't.

I've checked with LogCat that the condition is ok. The first time I open the dialog I see "SleepAlarm is NOT active". Once I've pressed the first button, when opening the dialog again I see "SleepAlarm is active"... But the buttons text are the same!

Here are the strings:

```
<string name="sleep_enable">Enable</string>
<string name="sleep_disable">Disable</string>
<string name="sleep_cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name="sleep_change">Change</string>
```

**Edit**: I've created the dialog using this code:

```
showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
```

The onCreateDialog implementation:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        timePicker = new SleepPickerDialog(this,this);
        return timePicker;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And SleepPickerDialog (extends TimePickerDialog) constructor:

```
public SleepPickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener){
    super(context, listener, MainActivity.sleep_hour, MainActivity.sleep_hour, true);
    changeState();
    this.setOnShowListener(showListener);
}
```

Algo, the onShowListener:

```
private DialogInterface.OnShowListener showListener = new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Cambiar botones
        changeState();
    }
};
```

I am missing something important?

**See accepted answer comments for the solution. I'm posting the complete code changes here:**

```
public SleepPickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener){
    super(context, listener, MainActivity.sleep_hour, MainActivity.sleep_hour, true);
    this.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE,(CharSequence)MainActivity.currentContext.getResources().getText(R.string.sleep_enable), sleepEnable);
    this.setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE,(CharSequence)MainActivity.currentContext.getResources().getText(R.string.sleep_cancel), sleepDisable);
    this.setOnShowListener(showListener);
}


private void changeState(){
    if(!SleepAlarm.isActive()){
        this.getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(R.string.sleep_enable);
        this.getButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setText(R.string.sleep_cancel);
    }
    else{
        this.getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(R.string.sleep_change);
        this.getButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setText(R.string.sleep_disable);
    }
    this.setTitle(R.string.sleep_title);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284165/can-i-change-the-label-of-the-set-button-in-a-timepickerdialog) as per this it works

try

```
yourTimePickerDialog.getButton(whichButton).setText("New Text"); (put the null check if needed)

or 

yourTimePickerDialog.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Find", yourTimePickerDialog);
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Exactly the same result.
Buttons retain the first text I set up on them. Setting the text a second time will do nothing.

Comment: not sure but can try this yourTimePickerDialog.getButton(whichButton).setText("New Text"); (put the null check if needed)

Comment: Yeah, that worked out very well! :) I'll update the question with the corrected code. Thank you!